# "Under the bright but faded lights". Why "faded" other than "fading"?

Tags: participles, lyrics

Alan Walker's "I'm Faded":

> Under the bright but faded lights

music: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60ItHLz5WEA

lyrics: https://genius.com/Alan-walker-faded-lyrics

Why was "faded" other than "fading" used?

---

@JasonBassford got my point. I thought the lights could not be both "bright" and "faded" at the same time.

It was my fault not to express my confusion explicitly & completely.

Comment: Because the fading has already happened—it's not still in the process of fading.

Comment: @JasonBassford So "**the bright but faded**" means the **light** has been **bright** at first but then becomes **faded**?

Comment: It means that while it's now bright, it has faded from when it was even brighter. (Perhaps it used be blinding and then faded to being simply bright.) At least, that would be a literal interpretation. Poetically, as in the case of song lyrics, the "faded" part may have to do with popularity rather than actual light. Popular figures, for instance, can be referred to as "bright lights." So, a movie star with bad press, struggling to find a part, could be a "bright but faded light."

Comment: It appears to me this question is about transitivity, passive voice, and past participle. The OP's confusion could be because _fade_ usually is an intransitive verb. I say "usually" because it can be used transitively.

Comment: When something fades it becomes faded.  It may still be fading, becoming more and more faded. To describe the thing as **faded** focuses on the fact that it is no longer as bright as it used to be. Something that is **fading** is *becoming* dimmer or less bright.

Comment: @JasonBassford You got my point. I thought the lights could not be both "bright" and "faded" at the same time.